# How to fix menu using z-index

Tags: css, z-index

I am struggling with something.
I have two menus (http://www.omicronsolucoes.com/mat/), and I need the logo to be over the first menu. For this, I added a z-index:1 on the first menu.
But now the links on the first menu wont work (because the z-index made them go behind).
How could I maintain the logo as it is and make the links working again?
Thanks.

Comment: You should modify the `padding` and `margin` of the entire logo row, so that it's actually below the top bar...

Comment: I ended up doing as rnevius suggested, once I wasnt able to make it work with the solutions the guys below suggested (thanks a lot!). 
Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your css, not sure from where it is coming but nav#ubermenu-main-13-header-menu is getting z-index as -1, so either you add this to your css file

```
nav#ubermenu-main-13-header-menu {
    z-index: 999 !important;
}
```

or try removing the z-index -1 from where is it getting applied

Answer (score 0):

Try adding position relative and a greater z-index to the li. Then either remove position:relative of the ul or override it with position:static:

```
.ubermenu-nav{
 position:static;
}

.ubermenu-nav > li{
 position:relative;
 z-index:11;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added `margin-top:-50px;` to `.logo` class

```
nav .logo {
  max-height: 100px !important;
  max-width: 200px !important;
  margin-top: -50px;
}
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofc34.png]